# Why do I get a bus error when running my assembly code

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64

I am on an M1 macbook on version 14.2 and I have the following code

```
.data
output_format:
    .asciz "Number: %lld\n"

.text
.globl _main

_main:
    mov x0, 1                   // File descriptor 1 (stdout)
    ldr x1, =output_format
    mov x2, 42                  // Your number goes here (e.g., 42)
    mov x16, 64                 // System call number for write
    svc 0

    mov x16, 1                  // System call number for exit
    mov x0, 0                   // Exit code 0
    svc 0
```

then when I compile it with `clang -arch arm64 -o output program.s` and try and run it with `./output` I get `zsh: bus error  ./output`

I have also tried using `as` and `ld`

First with `as -arch arm64 -o output.o program.s` and `ld -arch arm64 -o output output.o` but was then recieving `ld: dynamic executables or dylibs must link with libSystem.dylib for architecture arm64`

Then I tried with `as -arch arm64 -o output.o program.s` and `ld -arch arm64 -macosx_version_min 11.0 -e _main -lSystem -o output output.o` and recieved `ld: library not found for -lSystem`

Comment: `write` isn't `printf`, its third arg is a length in bytes.  Does `42` go off the end of a page perhaps?  I wouldn't have expected that.  But try with the actual length of the string, 13 bytes.  Perhaps you also have the wrong system-call numbers; I know for x86-64 macOS wants some high bits set for call numbers.